# socket io joining rooms dynamically in a namespace

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Am using socket io in Angular application/NodeJS application. I need to make the clients join rooms depending on the session object that they send to the server the problem is that if I use the `join` function in the `socket.on('event',function(){....})` the joining action wont be performed here is an example:

```
io.of('/session').on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('joinSession', function (room) {
      socket.join(room);
   });
  socket.on('message',function (data) 
  {
     socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('elementAdded', data.message);
   });
});
```

if I specify  the room directly everything works correctly here is an example

```
io.of('/session').on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.join("someStaticRoom");
  socket.on('message',function (data) 
  {
     socket.broadcast.to("someStaticRoom").emit('elementAdded', data.message);
   });
});
```

Comment: where is `joinSession` coming form? Where do you expect to trigger that event on the socket?

Comment: the `joinSession` comes from the  client this event is triggered after the connection

Comment: can you console log the event and confirm that it gets called? If it does get called, what is the value of the room parameter?

Comment: the event is being called correctly (if I add a console log in it , it works)  also I checked it is not a problem with the room value because I tried using `socket.join("someStaticRoom");` in the `joinSession ` event and it does not work neither

Comment: If you could provide some demo code to call joinSession, I could help debug a bit more. But otherwise I am also stumped.